# the reason he left the country

Tags: infinitives, negation, ambiguity

a. The reason he left the country was not to deal with this problem.

Is that sentence ambiguous?

I see two possible meanings:

1. The reason he left the country wasn't to deal with this problem.
2. The reason he left the country was to not deal with this problem.
   ( ... in order not to deal with this problem.)

Would you say that is correct?

Answer (score 1):

It has the first meaning.

To indicate the second you would write

> ... to not deal...

or

> ... to avoid dealing ...

Our sister site has some answers about the [order or "not" with infinitive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23152/order-of-not-with-infinitive)